# root directory for node module

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, package.json

I have a pretty standard node module using babel to transpile our code which is then output to a 'lib' folder.  the package.json points 'main' to 'lib/index.js' so that people can just `require('my-module')`

However, if I have a subdirectory (say my-module/server for example) then when they use my-module they have to do `require('my-module/lib/server')`.  I've seen people put post build steps that will copy package.json into lib, but that just feels hacky and wrong to me.  Is there any way in npm to specify a main *directory* whereby any require()'s of my module would start at that directory?  Then I can just have users do require('my-module/server') without the lib part...

Comment: I think it's more idiomatic to require("my-module").server, then have my-module.js export server explicitly.

Comment: the problem with that is that then webpack will include (or attempt to include) server code in the bundle.   At least until 2.0 comes out with tree shaking...

Comment: In that case, I would say it's more idiomatic to break up my-module into sub-components and do require("my-module-server"), which relies on something like require("my-module-common").  Then "my-module" would be a super package containing everything for convenience, but individual packages can be included separately.  Neither is exactly what you're looking for, but both are common approaches to the problem.

Comment: yeah, you're probably right.  :)  Was just hoping for something simpler

Comment: There is no answer to this question yet? What a problem. I don't want to build a index file because then the most basic require would have to do `require('my-module').main`. I think requiring the sub-part you need is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is that you have as main an index.js and on it all the submodules so you can do did something like `require('your-module').server`

Comment: the problem with this approach is that web pack will then include '.server' in the bundle

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without seeing your folder structure, but you can:

- use `module.exports =` to export the babel output
- symlink the other files into the directory

package.json

```
{ "main": "lib" }
```

lib/index.js

```
module.exports = require('./path-to-transpiled-code.js');

// Now also export all the other stuff in this folder dynamically

fs.readdirSync(DIRECTORY_TO_EXPORT, function (err, files) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (file !== 'index.js') {
      fs.symlinkSync(path.join(__dirname, file), path.join(DIRECTORY_TO_EXPORT, file));
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, the only thing you need is to point your's module main path inside package.json.

```
{
   "main": lib/index.js 
}
```

Where index.js is your module's main file.
For more info check npm documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main)

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you have a package `my-module`, and inside you have a subfolder `my-submodule`.
Your `my-module/package.json` file will contain the following line:

```
{
    ...,
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    ...
}
```

That will allow your package to be required by the line

```
var myMod = require('my-module');
```

To allow using the same syntax for submodule, all you have to do is to put package.json file in your submodule folder. It should contain the following:

```
{
    "main": "lib/index.js"
}
```

After that, you can use simple require syntax:

```
var mySubMod = require("my-module/my-submodule");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options how to accomplish your goal.

#### Export it all in *lib/index.js*

In your main module's entry point, you export everything that you would like to expose from your module.

- `+` Full control over what is part of the public API and what is considered "private"
- `+` Plays really nice with ES2015 modules specification
- `-` Does not satisfy your requirement to require the component (`server`) through a direct `require()` call with path to the server module

**Example:**

```
'use strict'

// this is whatever is the primary export of your module - be it a
// function, object or anything else which can have other properties
// assigned to it
const main = require('./main')
const server = require('./server')

module.exports = main
module.exports.server = server
// ...
```

**Usage:**

```
'use strict'

const mymodule = require('my-module')
const server = require('my-module').server
const { server } = require('my-module')

import { server } from 'my-module'
```

#### Create entry files for the components in your root

You can create separate files for each of the component you would like to expose as part of you public API in your module's root folder.

- `+` Satisfies your requirement of being able to require a component via specific path
- `-` Slightly more complex structure, requires extra file for each public component
- `-` Does not play well with ES2015 modules (you have to use the full path to the component and cannot use destructuring syntax)

**Example folder structure:**

```
my-module
├── lib
│   ├── index.js
│   └── server.js
└── server.js
```

The *my-module/server.js* file would only point to the actual implementation:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = require('./lib/server')
```

#### General notes

It should be noted that while technically possible, relying on full module paths by your consumers is not the best option, because the folder and file structure now becomes part of your API, so moving files around is suddenly a breaking change. Whenever I find myself in need to require a module's component this way, I treat it as if I was messing around with that module's internals and that I should expect my code to break even with a patch-version upgrade of that module.