# Make npm package sub-modules available

Tags: node.js, npm, requirejs

I have a private library meant to be shared between two code bases.
It is structured like so:

```
package.json
src/
 |_stores/
     |_user.js
 |_actions/
     |_user.js
```

The project is called "foo", I would like to do imports as follows:

```
require('foo/stores/user');
// OR
import User from 'foo/stores/user';
```

**What is the best way to do this?**

I've read [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282101/root-directory-for-node-module) which suggests I can copy the package.json into a `lib` folder but but it lacks further details?

### Things I've tried:

Since the code is ES2015/React/Flux I am using `babel` and `gulp` with a [prepublish script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to build a `lib` directory on `npm install` that looks like so:

```
package.json
src/
 |_stores/
     |_user.js
 |_actions/
     |_user.js
lib/
 |_stores/
     |_user.js
 |_actions/
     |_user.js
```

But, this only makes things available via: `require('foo/lib/stores/user')` so, I changed the prepublish script to build to the parent directory causing this:

```
package.json
stores/
 |_user.js
actions/
 |_user.js
src/
 |_stores/
     |_user.js
 |_actions/
     |_user.js
```

But, during local development (using npm link/file dependency) this gets a little messy.

I've also tried symlinking package.json to `lib` and setting `main` to point to `lib` but this didn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, what I was trying to do goes against convention. Since writing this question i've noticed the majority of libraries reference their dependencies via `package/lib/dep`. So in short I did the following as mentioned in the question:

Use webpack (or babel and gulp) with a [prepublish](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script to build a lib directory on npm install that looks like so:

```
package.json
src/
 |_stores/
     |_user.js
 |_actions/
     |_user.js
lib/
 |_stores/
     |_user.js
 |_actions/
     |_user.js
```

This will allow you to do the following: `require('foo/lib/stores/user')`